# PHP JSON unir 2 valores

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

Estoy creando un PHP para crear un JSON y cargar una tabla donde me consulta los registros de pedidos, donde tengo las direcciones y las indicaciones para llegar por separado. Quiero poder unir esas dos columnas para poder poner esos resultados en una sola columna de la tabla al momento de cargarla. Este es el PHP:

```
<?php
function toMoney($val,$r=2) 
{
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$n = $val; 
$c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format($n,$r);
$d = '.';
$t = ',';
$sign = ($n < 0) ? '-' : '';
$i = $n=number_format(abs($n),$r); 
$j = (($j = $i.length) > 3) ? $j % 3 : 0; 
return  $symbol.$sign .($j ? substr($i,0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;
}
$hostname = "Localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "aabdesig_registros";
$conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die ("Problemas con la conexion");
$requestData= $_REQUEST;
$sql = "SELECT *";
$sql.=" FROM registros where estado = 'pendiente'";
$query=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");
$data = array();

while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
$dir = $row["dir_obra"];

$nestedData=array(); 

$nestedData["hora"] = $row["hora"];
$nestedData["cliente"] = $row["cliente"];
$nestedData["dir_obra"] = $dir;
$nestedData["indicaciones"] = $row["indicaciones"];
$nestedData["fecha_entrega"] = $row["fecha_entrega"];
$nestedData["resistencia"] = $row["resistencia"];
$nestedData["m3"] = $row["m3"];

$data[] = $nestedData;
}
$json_data = array("data" => $data);
echo json_encode($json_data);
?>
```

Intente usar `$dir = $row["dir_obra"]."<br/>".$row["indicaciones"];` pero afecta toda la estructura del JSON al momento de cargarlo, y solo necesito unir ambos resultados y meterlos en una sola variable.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: En tu codigo no hay ninuna llamada Ajax.  Esto es probablemente la respuesta de PHP.

Comment: Por favor puedes darle un **var_dump($query)**, para saber que datos están capturando.

Comment: Este es el resultado:
`object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(21) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(5) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: ¿Así no te funciona: `$dir=$row["dir_obra"]."<br/>".$row["indicaciones"];` Y luego: `$nestedData["dir_obra"] = $dir;`?  ¿Por qué no funciona?  ¿Qué resultado arroja `var_dump($json_data);`?

Comment: Intente usarlo asi pero al momento de imprimir el JSON afecta toda la estructura. Ese JSON lo estoy usando para llenar una DataTable y cuando carga la pagina me manda un error de que el resultado de la solicitud es incorrecto o no se puede leer